# Is it possible to compile a class on the fly in Java without using external libraries?

Tags: java, runtime-compilation

It seems to me that the Java Compiler API allows to compile at runtime a class, writing its output (the .class file) to the file system. However, in-memory compilation is not supported. Is this correct ? or is possible to use this API to compile a class in memory (from a String) and instantiating such class afterwards ?

(I know I can compile the class to the file system and load it afterwards with a custom class loader, but I am wondering if I can compile it in memory, without passing by the file system).

Is there another alternative mechanism to do such in memory compilation using the J2SE only? 
[BeanShell](http://www.beanshell.org/home.html) (I library that can do what I want) mentions in its web page that it may be included in the J2SE at "some point in the future", however, the status of its [JSR](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=274) is "Dormant" (whatever does it mean).

**Update:**

Ideally, I would like to know if this can be done with the J2SE only (or if there are any expected enhancements to J2SE that will allow me to do this in, for example, Java 8). However, tips about how to do that requirying the JDK to be installed are also appreciated (thanks Evgeniy).

Comment: Compile the class then load it with a custom classloader...

Comment: What is the reason for the "no disk-access" requirement?

Comment: Hello @Thorbjorn, I need this for a library intended to be used by third parties. One reason is that I am attempting to minimize the requirements of my library (like the availability of a user temp directory).

Comment: I Would say that "please have a compiler in your class path" is a bit more restrictive than "please have a temp folder".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you dynamically compile and load external java classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21544446/how-do-you-dynamically-compile-and-load-external-java-classes)

Answer (score 4):

It is possible if you have JDK, java complier is in tools.jar which comes with JDK only. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/tools/package-summary.html

Comment: but I do not need the JDK for just using the Java Compiler API, right ?

Comment: right, but ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler(); will return null then

Comment: I see, but you think it would allow me to do the in memory compilation that I need, correct ? Are you aware of licensing issues I should take into consideration ? Probably the JDK is more restricted than the J2SE.

Comment: 1) http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JDK-6/CompilingfromMemory.htm 2) I am 100% sure there's no licencing issues

Comment: You need something _implementing_ the Java Compiler API.  If you do not drag in e.g. the Eclipse compiler in a jar, you need the JDK to provide the compiler in javac.

Answer (score 1):

> Java Compiler API .. in-memory compilation is not supported. Is this correct?

No. The [STBC](http://pscode.org/stbc/) uses the `JavaCompiler` to do exactly that.

> ..and instantiating such class afterwards?

The STBC does not go as far as trying to load/run the class, but I believe it should be possible.  I imagine it might require a custom 'in memory' class loader though.

> ..the JavaCompiler API can do that independently if the JDK is installed or not?

From the page..

> ### System Requirements
>
> STBC will run on any computer with a version 1.6+ Java <del>Plug-In</del>* JDK (AKA SDK).
>
> `*` The API that STBC uses is merely a public interface to the compiler in the `tools.jar` that is distributed *only with JDKs* (though the 'public JRE' of the JDK also seems to acquire a `tools.jar`). ..

Comment: I am a bit confussed, the JavaCompiler API can do that independently if the JDK is installed or not ? (as Evgeniy said ?)

Comment: Please make your answers self standing.  Answers on the form "please read the whole documentation to my pet project" have room for improvement.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen The answer was edited to include the relevant part, soon after I made that (now deleted) comment.

Answer (score 1):

JeKa (https://jeka.dev) provides a rich set of class to make it simpler than using JdkTool.